# 3 column fluid page : BIG ISSUES

Tags: css, css-float

Everything looked great until I widened my site.
I have checked the code, firebugged all and for 2days I have only gotten more frustrated and am praying someone here could be of help - maybe a fresh set of eyes will help.
I have linked the page and the cssdesk code for you see what is going on.
Thanking you in advance.
In css desk the columns are correct but on the website it looks like everything is pushed down for some reason.

http://www.cssdesk.com/BVCf2

http://jason.carpedp.com/coinlogistics/charities-co-ordinator/aviation-sector/

Comment: Do you realize those empty <p></p> tags between your divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use closing p without opening p and don't use `--` in comments, some browsers interpretate it as end of comment.

```
<div class="left"><!--COLLEFT--NOTHING-->
     </p>
     <div class="airport"><!--CENTER--><br/>
     </p>
     <h4>AIRPORTS</h4>
```

use w3c validator to find more errors:
http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks Abim.. - THAT IT DID. who would have know. I have been tugging at this with light to be seen and such a simple issue. WOW Big thanks for quick response as well.

Comment: you'r welcome. I remember once I searched this issue with the '--' in comments too... If the answer solved your problem you may mark it as accepted and/or give it an upvote. thanks

Comment: ok -1st time using this amazing site - how do mark resolved and upvote an inquiry?

Comment: Abim - I did a validation check now as suggested and WOW alot of closing tags are highlighted. I am now confused about these errors highlighted. Example: Line 230, Column 495: Stray end tag span.…e over</br><b>€ 100 MILLION. <b></span**<**a title="SERVICES" href="http://jason.…

Comment: Validating is a step  that a web developer should do after every bigger code change. You can mark the answer as accepted using the green tick on the left side. Take a quick look at the basics of SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the code and did a quick download of the page and dropped it into a HTML editor.

From what I gathered, there is a blank

tag (code line 86 on my editor) in the airports column which is setting everything down a level.

After removing that it started displaying fine on my side again.

Original

```
 <div class="airport"><!--CENTER--><br>
 <p></p>
 <h4>AIRPORTS</h4>
 <p><img alt="Donation boxes are strategically placed in busy areas of the airport" src="./Aviation Sector - Coin Logistics_files/airport.jpg">
 </p>
 <p>With a substantial rise in international and foreign travel in recent years; the volume of foreign coins entering and departing the airports have increased. This makes airports the perfect location for the donation boxes to be located, giving travelers the opportunity to rid themselves of their unwanted change and enabling them to perform the good deed of donating to the designated charity and allowing their small change to make a big difference.
 </p>
 </div>
```

New

```
     <div class="airport"><!--CENTER--><br>

     <h4>AIRPORTS</h4>
     <p><img alt="Donation boxes are strategically placed in busy areas of the airport" src="./Aviation Sector - Coin Logistics_files/airport.jpg">
     </p>
     <p>With a substantial rise in international and foreign travel in recent years; the volume of foreign coins entering and departing the airports have increased. This makes airports the perfect location for the donation boxes to be located, giving travelers the opportunity to rid themselves of their unwanted change and enabling them to perform the good deed of donating to the designated charity and allowing their small change to make a big difference.
     </p>
     </div>
```

Comment: There you go Jaay, I've put in the only change I made to the code to get it working.

Comment: strange there was no '<p></p>' under the 'div class' airports on a '</br>' so am even more confused. the code in CSSdesk link is the exact code. I have no idea why or how you got that extra code. Can't find it in my side.

Comment: Hmm well that is strange, I saw above that you've found a solution so glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

if you check your html code in firebug you 'll found some unnecessary empty tags like `<p></p>` and `<br/>` just remove them and that is all.

Comment: in real HTML code there is no empty tag, but a closing tag </p> but firebug makes HTML automatically valid to parse it, so it's not recommended to use it for validating HTML

Comment: yes fire bug tweak some html automatically you need to remove unwanted tags and never use closing tag if it is not opened.

Comment: Thank you  thank you and thank you  ALL> so how do I resolve / clsoe  this question as it has been answered now?

Comment: sorry - was blind to the tck on the side of comments area. Did ask another question regarding the errors found on validation tool. most of my > are highlighted.

Comment: @abdul Thanks - question was regarding the highlighted end tags on alot of my code. Example : Stray end tag span....most competitive exchange rates.</span**>**<a title="SERVICES" href="http://jason.…